# Is negative testing possible in TestNG?

Tags: testng

I wanna check if a site allows a user to forregister using the same email multiple times. I use TestNG framework. How can I do negative testing for the below case?

```
  @Test
  public void testRejestracja() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.link.inlblk > strong")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("register_tab")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("userEmailRegister")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("userEmailRegister")).sendKeys("an@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("userPassRegister")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("userPassRegister")).sendKeys("an12");
    driver.findElement(By.id("button_register")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.tdnone > span")).click();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do this :

- You first create a separate utility method which would accept credentials and return `true` if the registration was successful and `false` otherwise.
- You now invoke this utility method from within a `@Test` method passing in the required credentials and run assertion on the returned value.